# API for linking posts with personal blogs

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, api

I started my own blog after reading several posts from Joel and Jeff about the importance of writing. Recently Jeff [wrote a post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-write-without-writing.html) about how helping other users in Stack Overflow has similar benefits.

I believe it would be great if we could have some type of API that links our answers to other users into our personal blogs or the other way around. Sometimes a question gives me an idea for a whole new post, but most of the time I would just like to have the same text of my answer as an article in my blog.

This would certainly motivate me to write better answers. I could also add a link sort of "Read more..." if I want to extend with details. From a selfish point of view, bloggers can get some incoming links from such a great place as SO.

At a minimun, even a standard way to add that "Read more..." link would help. Because otherwise I would get a bad feeling of self advertisement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be against this.  A link from your answers to your personal blog should not be automatic.  It wouldn't contribute anything to your answer in the vast majority of cases, so it would just be noise.

As for linking from your blog to your answers on SO, every registered user on SO has an RSS feed that you should be able to incorporate into a blog widget.

Comment: I think he's talking more about automatically creating blog entries every time you post an answer, which is already possible.

Comment: Hmm... reading again he want to go both ways, where the the api would allow him to expand on the entry in the blog (to provide context, etc).  I agree that this (and anything else that pushes part of your answer off of the Stack Overflow proper) is a bad idea.

Comment: Adding to that: the main reason I dislike finding the aggressive SOFU scrapers in Google (apart from the advertisement revenue that I feel should be SOFU's), is that their content is often not kept in sync with SOFU. So, when using RSS for a blog, I'd hope one gets updates (for edits) too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this already.  Every user has an RSS feed (mine is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/3043)), and some blog engines support "re-posting" entries from an RSS feed (usually with some form of attribution about the source). A qucik google search shows that wordpress can do this via a plugin, for example.